# IoC/DI in the face of winforms and other generated code

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, code-generation, inversion-of-control

When using dependency injection (DI) and inversion of control (IoC) objects will typically have a constructor that accepts the set of dependencies required for the object to function properly.

For example, if I have a form that requires a service to populate a combo box you might see something like this:

```
// my files
public interface IDataService {
    IList<MyData> GetData();
}

public interface IComboDataService {
    IList<MyComboData> GetComboData();
}

public partial class PopulatedForm : BaseForm {
    private IDataService service;
    public PopulatedForm(IDataService service) {
        //...
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

This works fine at the top level, I just use my IoC container to resolve the dependencies:

```
var form = ioc.Resolve<PopulatedForm>();
```

But in the face of generated code, this gets harder. In winforms a second file composing the rest of the partial class is generated. This file references other components, such as custom controls, and uses no-args constructors to create such controls:

```
// generated file: PopulatedForm.Designer.cs
public partial class PopulatedForm {
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        this.customComboBox = new UserCreatedComboBox();
        // customComboBox has an IComboDataService dependency
    }
}
```

Since this is generated code, I can't pass in the dependencies and there's no easy way to have my IoC container automatically inject all the dependencies.

One solution is to pass in the dependencies of each child component to `PopulatedForm` even though it may not need them directly, such as with the `IComboDataService` required by the `UserCreatedComboBox`. I then have the responsibility to make sure that the dependencies are provided through various properties or setter methods. Then, my `PopulatedForm` constructor might look as follows:

```
public PopulatedForm(IDataService service, IComboDataService comboDataService) {
    this.service = service;
    InitializeComponent();
    this.customComboBox.ComboDataService = comboDataService;
}
```

Another possible solution is to have the no-args constructor to do the necessary resolution:

```
public class UserCreatedComboBox {
    private IComboDataService comboDataService;
    public UserCreatedComboBox() {
        if (!DesignMode && IoC.Instance != null) {
            comboDataService = Ioc.Instance.Resolve<IComboDataService>();
        }
    }
}
```

Neither solution is particularly good.  What patterns and alternatives are available to more capably handle dependency-injection in the face of generated code? I'd love to see both general solutions, such as patterns, and ones specific to C#, Winforms, and Autofac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there is no silver-bullet solution here. I would use property injection in this case to leave parameterless constructor. Also I personally do not like injection of services into UI classes, I prefer injecting some kind of Presenters there. Then you have a property Presenter which will be set by IoC container and in setter of this property you will have your initializing code.

Out of your two solutions I do not like second one especially because of referencing IoC container in your code which is bad IMO.

Comment: Re: referencing IoC container - I absolutely agree. I beginning to think that, as you allude to, a design which requires much more than a presentation model within the UI code will suffer in testability and good separation of concerns.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that your UI, especially sub-elements of your UI, shouldn't need to be provided with any services.

It's hard to judge how feasible this is for your app, but MVC or MVP is meant to avoid this need.

I would try to redesign so that a controller is responsible for interacting with services and that controller gives the view elements everything they need, rather than letting the view elements ask for what they need.